# Matlab function perfcurve falsely asserts ROC AUC = 1

Tags: matlab, roc

The perfcurve function in Matlab falsely, asserts AUC=1 when two records are clearly misclassified for reasonable cutoff values.
If I run the same data through a confusion matrix with cutoff 0.5, the accuracy is rightfully below 1.
The MWE contains data from one of my folds. I noticed the problem because I saw perfect auc with less than perfect accuracy in my results.

I use Matlab 2016a and Ubuntu 16.4 64bit.

```
% These are the true classes in one of my test-set folds
classes = transpose([ones(1,9) 2*ones(1,7)])
% These are predictions from my classifier
% Class 1 is very well predicted
% Class 2 has two records predicted as class 1 with threshold 0.5
confidence = transpose([1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.9999 1.0 1.0...
    1.0 1.0 0.0 0.7694 0.0 0.9917 0.0 0.0269 0.002])
positiveClass = 1
% Nevertheless, the AUC yields a perfect 1
% I understand why X, Y, T have less values than classes and confidence
% Identical records are dealt with by one point on the ROC curve
[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(classes, confidence, positiveClass)
% The confusion matrix for comparison
threshold = 0.5
confus = confusionmat(classes,(confidence<threshold)+1)
accuracy = trace(confus)/sum(sum(confus))
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that there is *another cutoff* where the separation is perfect.

Try:

```
threshold = 0.995
confus = confusionmat(classes,(confidence<threshold)+1)
accuracy = trace(confus)/sum(sum(confus))
```

Comment: But roc performs a sweep across cutoffs anyway. So if you look at the output of X, Y and T on the console for example:0.9917
    0.7694

Comment: @user7019377 It sweeps through all possible cutoffs and find that one of them has a perfect separation, so you get AUC = 1.

Comment: Thresholds of 0.9917 and 0.7694 in T for example will lead to classifying those class 2 examples as class 1. Yet Y says perfect TPR (specificity) and X says no FPR (perfect sensitivity).

(Pressed enter too soon by accident, can't find edit button since I am new here.)

Comment: I see now, just not sure if that's what I want. But this isn't the Roc curve's fault I suppose.

Comment: It may not be what you want but Matlab is correct saying that AUC = 1.

Comment: Since this one cutoff that perfectly separates is 0.9999, the AUC is approx. 1. If only one cutoff could perfectly separate and it would be significantly lower than 1, AUC would not be 1, right?

Comment: Sorry again, even not that.

Comment: @user7019377 The AUC is *exactly* 1. ROC analysis is not impacted by the value of the threshold *at all*. It can be 10e-10 or 10e10, if you have a perfect separation your AUC is 1.